# Android Sender Seekbar status is inaccurate

Tags: google-cast, google-cast-sdk

Once in a while, seekbar values of ExpandedControllerActivity goes out of sync after back to back playback. The max value is 1 and current progress is 1 and this causes the thumb to be at the end irrespective of the actual playback duration. Receiver has correct duration values and sends correct values (when using chrome inspect).

Are there any recommendation to debug these issues at client end as ExpandedControllerActivity source code is obfuscated.

Comment: @leon-nicholls Would you have you tips? RemoteMediaClient.getMediaInfo().getStreamDuration() returns -1 in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar issue tracked at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/120069343.

In our case, this was resolved by receiver setting stream duration explicitly.